# python telegram bot stops working after server reload

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I use `python-telegram-bot`

this is my `main.py`

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, CallbackContext


def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Sends a message with inline buttons attached."""
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Connect wallet", callback_data='connectwallet'),
        ],

   update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)


def button(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Parses the CallbackQuery and updates the message text."""
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    
    if query.data == 'connectwallet':
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=f'This is test msg')
        

def main() -> None:
    """Run the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater('180666756:AAGX__token__WdNO_YOVa7nA35EBXc')

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help_command))

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling( )
    # timeout=300

    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But whenever I shut down main.py, change some code and restart it( Using `ctrl+c` and then `python3 main.py`)
Telegram bot freezes and stops responding to user commands. Sometimes it get's back to life, sometimes it doesn't and i need to restart bot from telegram.

I've tried to search a solution but didn't find it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "restart bot from telegram"? Also please make sure to enable [logging](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/#logging) to make sure that you see exceptions that happen at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of telegram api limitations and if you are in local host maybe your ram and internet be slow. use heroku for deploying. Hope it will work also if you know threading you can use it it's good with its issue. Also make sure to enable logging if you need codes ask me I will give.